# Project build error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting below error while building the project.

> Error  57  Assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpressExtensions\tsd5dblb.1t2\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll    Mitchell.WCS.FSAutomation.TfsHandler

Any help?

Comment: I think this is dependencies versions conflict.

Comment: Let me read this for you The assembly "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client" that you have added to your project internally uses another assembly "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common (v 14)".Also you have explicitly added same "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common(v 11)" assembly.so you see there are two assemblies but different versions.hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have projects which references `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client` but one references Version 11, other 14. This may be caused by:

- your mistake in selecting proper library from `Add reference` menu
- updating NuGet package

I suggest you check all assemblies - compare reference to this library and check it's version. That's all.